# @Transactional(rollbackfor=Exception.class) for two daoimpl class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

in my project I am using two transactional classes. Each class contains save method. When I add `@Transactional(roolbackFor=Exception.class)` annotation into these classes, for using like

```
@Component
public class CallerClass{
@Autowired    
private TransactionClass1 class1;
@Autowired    
private TransactionClass2 class2;

public void saveOperation(){    
    try{
        class1.save();
        class2.save();
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
}
}
```

if class1.save method is executed without Exception but class2.save method throws an Exception, then class1.save operation is rolled back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

To have this behavior, the method containing these two calls would have to be transactional as well. Moreover, If you instantiate your classes using `new`, the transactional interceptor won't be used. You have to get instances of these classes from the application contect, or (preferrably), by dependency injection.

Comment: @Autowired actually this two objects

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any @Transactional annotations for method, that contains calls of save(), than if there is an exception if class2.save(), class1.save() should not be rolled back.